# PHP and excel reading - mind-boggling

Tags: php

So I have this small "xls" file that's actually a tab-delimited txt file.
In it, I have a value that looks like this: '000000000003014610'. When opened with excel, the value reads correctly as "3014610", however by splitting this by tabs and reading it with PHP I get unexpected results - intval() gives always 0, ltrim($val,'0') gives me the string intact, and strlen($val) gives an amazing 35

Does anyone know how to get around this, and what the problem might be?

Thanks

Comment: Could you do `var_dump( $val )` and post the results, please?

Comment: Can you show a full example row and the code you are using to read it?

Comment: string(35) "000000000003014610"
funny thing that before trim() it's string(37)

Comment: Are you sure there are no HTML tags or whitespace (tabs etc) there? Take a look at the page source to make sure.

Comment: yes. I'm using Notepad++ and I set it to show all symbols and hidden characters

Comment: Any chance of seeing the file?

Comment: a typical line looks like this: (0040 is actually the forth line in the file, the second value is the value we are talking about and third comes the textual representation of the code
"00040 000000000003014610 TEXT HERE"

Comment: try running `for($i=0;$i<strlen($val);++$i){echo"'{$val{$i}}' - 0x".dechex(ord($val{$i})).PHP_EOL;}` so you will see every char with it's hex code in this string, so you can determine where are some hidden chars

Comment: thanks.as it turns out, the digits are sometimes interpolated with non-ascii characters- 8�0�0�8�5�3�2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that strlen() is correct in that its a 35 character string and you're trying to cast that into an int and its too big.  Take for example:

```
$cell = explode(" ", $rawCellData);
$cell_num = (int) $cell[0];
$cell_data = (int) $cell[1];
$cell_text = (string) $cell[2];

echo "$cell_num $cell_data $cell_text<br>";
```

And you'll see that $cell_data doesn't equal what it should.

Check out these two references:
[php type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) AND [php string conversion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

But essentially, since the string starts with zero, php is treating it as an int.

Comment: ended up using $str=preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\s\s+]/", '',$str); to replace some weird characters that shouldn't be there at all